# Trying to learn generics in java and compiler throws cannot reference variable this in non static context even so im not implecently calling this

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package generictypes;

/**
 *
 * @author Capn_Clunks
 */
public class GenericTypes 
{

    public class Queue<E>//Inbetween <> denotes a generic type
    {
        private E[] elements;//[]Denotes a array type
        private int head, tail;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Queue(int size)
        {
            if(size < 2)
            {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("" + size);
            }
                elements = (E[]) new Object[size];
                head=0;
                tail=0;
         }

        void insert(E element) throws QueueFullException
        {
            if(isFull())
            {
                throw new QueueFullException();
            }
            elements[tail]= element;
            tail = (tail+1)%elements.length;
        }

        boolean isFull()
        {
            return (tail +1)%elements.length == head;
        }

        boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return head == tail;
        }

        E remove() throws QueueEmptyException
        {
            if(isEmpty())
            {
                throw new QueueEmptyException();
            }
            E element = elements[head];
            head = (head + 1) % elements.length;
            return element;
        }


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws QueueFullException, QueueEmptyException
    {
        Queue<String> queue = new Queue<String>(6);//This is the offender
        System.out.println("Empty: " + queue.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Copied directly out of a book so should work, confused as to why because I can't make static and I just wanted to compile as a example to myself to demonstrate the concept.

Answer (score -1):

Your `Queue` class is an inner (non-static nested) class of `GenericTypes`. Move it to a top-level class, most simply by making `Queue` the top-level and getting rid of `GenericTypes` entirely.